# Item keeps getting added to Tableview even if I just have one in my DB

Tags: swift, firebase, tableview

I have this code and I call it every time I click on a button and call another viewcontroller where I call fetchVinylData inside viewWillappear. The problem is everytime I click a button to go to this VC it adds one item to the tableview even if I only have one inside my database.I am guessing is because my array keeps getting fed even if there is only one record in my database.How do I delete from my array so I don't get many values inside my tableView only the ones that is saved on my firebase database?I tried to add myArray.removeAll() inside fetchrequest before I load the vinyl to the array but my app crashs eventually

```
func fetchVinylData() {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    dbRef.child("vinylsOUT").child(currentUID).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> else { return }
        let vinyl = Vinyl(dictionary: dictionary)

        self.vinyls.append(vinyl)
        self.vinyls.sort(by: { (vinyl1, vinyl2) -> Bool in
            return vinyl1.artist < vinyl2.artist
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
}
```

thank yo very much

Comment: My guess is you are calling this function 2 times and also better use sorted than sort .

Answer (score 0):

You are appending to your array every time you get back data from Firebase:
 - self.vinyls.append(vinyl)

You can just override your current vinyls array by doing:

```
self.vinyls = [Vinyl]()
```

before you fetch the new data from Firebase. 
That would look like this:

```
func fetchVinylData() {
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    guard let currentUID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }

    self.vinyls = [Vinyl]() // <- here you reset the array 

    dbRef.child("vinylsOUT").child(currentUID).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject> else { return }
        let vinyl = Vinyl(dictionary: dictionary)

        self.vinyls.append(vinyl)
        self.vinyls.sort(by: { (vinyl1, vinyl2) -> Bool in
            return vinyl1.artist < vinyl2.artist
        })
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
}
```

Comment: I made the change you told me but I still see one item even if database has no one item saved.thank you

Comment: And your array is empty when you call "self.tableView.reloadData()"?
Do you have sections in your tableView?

Comment: First time I load app my array is empty if I add some item to it by calling fetchVinylData it loads to TV but if I remove item from database and try to remove from TV by loading nothing from database then I still see one record.I am thinking maybe it the observer method the is not being called since DB is empty isn't it? I have only one section

Comment: I see. There is another observer:
.observe(.childAdded)

Try it with this one

Comment: I am calling fecthVinylData inside viewWillAppear so it gets called everytime I load my VC right or should I call it only once inside viewDidLoad?

Comment: but it is working when I add items to tv it adds the problem is when I delete all I still see one last item if I reopen my app then I don't see nothing.I need to manage this array without having to quit my app.

Comment: self.vinyls = [Vinyl]() empties your array. So there is no need to restart the app. 
Is there maybe something wrong in your cellForRow(at: ) ?

Comment: here it is     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! VinylsOutListCell

        cell.vinyl = vinyls[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }

Comment: Looks right. Can you set a breakpoint in the line "self.tableView.reloadData()" and see if you array contains anything

Comment: I added the call to a function inside viewWillAppear then i added breakpoint inside fetchvinyldata..first time I enter vc viewwillappear triggers function call and stops at breakpoint second time I enter VC the function does not get triggered again.